# Find a matrix such that the image is equal to the solution space of a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

$x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 − x_4 = 0$

$−x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 0$

$x_1 + x_3 = 0$

Consider the following matrix $A$ from the system of equations:

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{crc}
 1 &  2 &  1 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & 1 &  1\\
 1 &  0 &  1 & 0\\
\end{array}\right)$$

1) Find a basis of the solution space $W (Ax=0).$

2) Find a Matrix $A$ such that the image of the transformation $T: \mathbb R^6 \to \mathbb R^4$ equals  $W (\mathrm{im}(T)=W)$

3) Find a Matrix $A$ such that the kernel of the transformation  $F: \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^6$ equals $W (\mathrm{ker}(F)=W)$

**My solution so far:**

I found the solution space to be a line. I performed GJ elimination and got

$$\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 x_1 \\
 x_2 \\
 x_3 \\
 x_4
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{crc}
 1 \\
 1/2 \\
 -1 \\
 1
\end{array}\right) \cdot t$$ 
where $t$ is a free variable.

So a basis (one of the many) is the vector 
$$ u =\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 1 \\
 1/2 \\
 -1 \\
 1
\end{array}\right)$$

$W = span(u)$

2) We are looking for a matrix $B$ such that $B\cdot x = u$. The matrix $B$ will be a $4\times 6$ matrix.

Let the first row of the matrix be

$$B = \left(\begin{array}{crc}
 a_1 &  b_1 &  c_1 & d_1 & e_1 & f_1\\
 .. & .. & .. &  .. & .. & ..\\
 .. & .. & .. &  .. & .. & ..\\
 .. & .. & .. &  .. & .. & ..\\
\end{array}\right)$$

and this is valid:

$a_1x_1+b_1x_2+c_1x_3+d_1x_4+e_1x_5+f_1x_6 = 1$

We notice though that

$a_1=-a_3=a_4$
$b_1=-b_3=b_4$ 
.
.
.
$f_1=-f_3=f_4$

and that:

$a_2=\frac{1}{2}a_1$ and $b_2=\frac{1}{2} b_1$ and so on..

What I end up with is with a Matrix that looks like this:

$$B = \left(\begin{array}{crc}
 a_1 &  b_1 &  c_1 & d_1 & e_1 & f_1\\
 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right)$$

which can't be right since what we get is a scalar product.

Please help me. I don't know what I am doing wrong!

Thanks :)

Happy New Year to you all! :)

Comment: I guess the `solution space` means the solutions space of the equation $A\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$?

Comment: Yes it is... sorry I read wrong!

Answer (score 0):

1) There's an error:It is evident the third equation can't be verified if all coordinates are positive. Actually the third coordinate of $u$ is $-1$.

2) Remember the image of a linear map is generated by the column-vectors of its matrix in a given basis. So all column-vectors of A should be colinear with $u$.

3) You can take for $A$ a 6×4 matrix that's made up of two 3×4 blocks which have kernel equal to $W.$ The simplest is to take these blocks equal to the $A$ of question 1).

Indeed, since $W=\ker T\subset \mathbf R^4$, if we set $ F=T\oplus T\colon \mathbf R^3\oplus\mathbf R^3\simeq \mathbf R^6\rightarrow \mathbf R^4$, we have that $\ker F=\ker T\cap\ker T=W$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake out. I understand what you mean with (2)... But again don't we end up with a matrix like B in the end when we GJ eliminate the other rows? Plus can you explain in more detail (3)? I feel a little lost. Thanks!

Comment: The image of the transformation with matrix $B$ is generated by $(a_1, 0,0,0), \ (b_1, 0,0,0), \dots$, so that it is generated by the first vector of the canonical basis if one of $a_1, b_1, \dots$ is non-zero. You just have to take the matrix of $T$ and complete it with two more columns so that it doesn't add anything to the image. E.g. complete it a two zero-columns. I added some explanation for 3); is that clearer?

Comment: I'm trying to understand it :/

Comment: One formula was incomplete, thus hard to understand. I've updated it. Did you hear of block operations on matrices?

Comment: Nope what is it?

Comment: It's a little long to explain within a comment. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix). In some words, it corresponds to direct sum decompositions of either the source space, or the image, or both. Here I decompose $\mathbf R^6$ as $\mathbf R^3\times \mathbf R^3$.